# Why is this pattern match necessary?

Tags: rust

I am reading [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/net/addr.rs.html#199-205) and is like some lines of code are not necessary.

For example in the example below, is the `match` really useful? Why is it needed? Seems like repetitive code? Maybe the compiler resolve this and it is written only for expressiveness?

```rust
#[stable(feature = "sockaddr_setters", since = "1.9.0")]
pub fn set_port(&mut self, new_port: u16) {
    match *self {
        SocketAddr::V4(ref mut a) => a.set_port(new_port),
        SocketAddr::V6(ref mut a) => a.set_port(new_port),
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what part of this you think is unnecessary. The compiler can't resolve `a.set_port(...)` unless it knows the type of `a`, and to do that you have to peer into the `enum`. There are two possibilities, so you have to account for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` is required to access the inner value. A [`SocketAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html) can contain either a [`SocketAddrV4`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.SocketAddrV4.html) or a [`SocketAddrV6`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.SocketAddrV6.html), so you need to handle both possibilities.